# How to allow outbound requests from a Google Cloud Run cluster on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-cloud-run

**Cloud Run enabled clusters disable outbound network traffic from any pod by default**

After creating a cluster with Cloud Run by following the documentation, one can check that all requests from inside a pod in the cluster, not even only from Knative service pods but really from any pod, will return 404. It's not clear which configuration sets this, but it's clear that it happens via creating a cluster with Cloud Run enabled.

In consequence, we're not able to, for instance, install helm on this cluster. In fact, we can't install anything that will require an external request from a pod.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1 - Follow Cloud Run setup [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup)

2 - Start a simple alpine pod in your cluster:
`kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never alpine --image=alpine sh`

3 - do any external request like: `wget www.google.com`

Cloud Run also documents this behaviour and explains how to [enable outbound traffic](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup#enabling_all_outbound_network_access)

Although, I followed this steps and still couldn't enable the traffic. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or it's really not working as it should.

**Update**

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55861559/3165889, this happens on the current Istio version Cloud Run uses, but should be changed on the 1.1 release where egress will be enabled for all outbound requests by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the Cloud Run on GKE setup documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup#enabling_outbound_network_access

This will not be necessary soon, as it will be enabled by default by moving to Istio 1.1 where outbound traffic policy allows any egress traffic, by default.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I've tried editing the ConfigMap as documented. Although, after running `kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never alpine --image=alpine sh` again, I still didn't get outbound traffic enabled. Only thing that worked for me was actually disabling istio-injection with the label on the default namespace.

Comment: Another note, but this is another topic, is that my pods are not getting removed after the above command. Only the alpine container gets killed. So the istio-sidecar container keeps the pod alive.

Comment: Sounds like a new question.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your posted problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it really didn't. As I had mentioned before your answer in the description: "Cloud Run also documents this behaviour and explains how to enable outbound traffic. Although, I followed this steps and still couldn't enable the traffic". I've also heard from other people they couldn't get it working by the official documentation. What really helped was disabling istio-injection completely. I'll provide more feedback on how did I change the ConfigMap and perhaps you can try to assist me. I'll ping you soon when I update it.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to disable the istio-sidecar on the default namespace:
`kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=disabled`

More details: https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/1202#note_164285838